Select * from Table strange behavior
Wanting to check a table from my mariaDB database, I got an error that I don't understand :
MariaDB [database]> select * from Requests;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' from Requests' at line 1

The thing is, if I do this one, it's working perfectly :
MariaDB [database]> select * from `Requests`;

This error never happened before, first time today.
If I do for example :
MariaDB [database]> Delete from Requests;

It's working perfectly.
The biggest problem is that now, my application is not working when I try to use Requests.
If someone had the same problem recently or understand why this is happening, it would be a big help ! I tried to delete the data from Requests, but nothing changed. And doing the command for another table works fine.

Is the char before * a standard space (ASCII 32=0x20) or any other space?

@Wiimm it is a standard space

Try using backticks around your table and column names, additionally check the database's case sensitivity.

@TrushabaB.Jadeja That's in the question, it worked with backticks.

But if the problem were that Requests is a reserved word (which it isn't) the error would say "near 'Requests'", not "near ' from Requests'".

The problem is probably with the character after *.

Have you tried to use other sql client? and also have you selected the database?
USE database_name

Yes I have selected my database. What's strange is that it was functional until yesterday. If I try with any other table than Requests, there is no problem.
